# How to handle class initialization when using brace-enclosed initializer lists

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I'm working with a custom C++ library, CPSTL, for Arduino, which includes a `cpstd::vector` class that is designed to work with `cpstd::initializer_list`, `cpstd::initializer_list` is supposed to mimic `std::initializer_list`.

However, I'm having trouble initializing a `cpstd::vector` using brace-enclosed initializer lists.

I've looked up many sources online, and it seems there is not a lot of information in the topic, but came up to things such as [FastArduino: initializer list](https://jfpoilpret.github.io/fast-arduino-lib/initializer__list_8h_source.html), and [Arduino STL: Initializer list](https://github.com/mike-matera/ArduinoSTL/blob/master/src/initializer_list). Giving me hopes that it is actually possible. (I can't use those libraries, because they lack the build system generation tools on the library I am developing, they also lack on customizability, and also as a good learning experience)

I've tried various approaches, but I keep getting the error:

> could not convert '{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to 'cpstd::vector'.

Here's an example of the code that's causing the issue:

```cpp
    cpstd::vector<unsigned char> myVector = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

I have already implemented a custom `cpstd::initializer_list` and constructor that should handle this, but the issue persists. Is there something specific to the Arduino environment that could be causing this issue?

Additional Information:

- I have verified that the `cpstd::initializer_list` is correctly defined and included in my code.
- The `cpstd::vector` class is included and accessible.
- I have reviewed my `cpstd::vector` class, and the constructor for `cpstd::initializer_list` is correctly implemented.
- While reading the error log, I noticed that `std::initializer_list` constructor has two parameters, a pointer to the data, and also a variable telling the length of the braced enclosed list, however I noticed that the list ends up casting to a single parameter, hence having no possible constructor to call

***What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to initialize `cpstd::vector` using brace-enclosed initializer lists in the Arduino environment? I think the main issue is with boards that have no STL support. (i.e. AVR based boards)***

I've came to the conclusion that it will not be possible to create such constructors/operators due to compiler limitations, I think I've tried anything that came to mind. But I don't want to give up on this without knowing if there is a workaround.

**edit (removed previous code snippets for clarity, added minimal code example reproducing the error) :**

minimal sketch reproducing the error:

```
#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <stddef.h> 

namespace cpstd {

  template<typename T>
  class initializer_list {
  public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = const T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using const_iterator = const T*;

  private:
    const_iterator _M_array;
    size_type _M_len;

    constexpr initializer_list(const T* array, size_type size) noexcept
      : _M_array(array), _M_len(size) {}

  public:
    constexpr initializer_list() noexcept
      : _M_array(nullptr), _M_len(0) {}

    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept {
      return _M_len;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
      return _M_array;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept {
      return _M_array + _M_len;
    }
  };
}

template<typename T>
class exampleClass{
  protected:
    T buffer[10];
    size_t len;

  public:
    exampleClass(): len(0) {}
    exampleClass(cpstd::initializer_list<T> il){
      len = il.size();
      for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
        buffer[i] = *(il.begin()+i);
      }
    }

    exampleClass& operator=(cpstd::initializer_list<T> il){
      len = il.size();
      for(auto i = il.begin(); i < il.end(); i++){
        buffer[i] = *i;
      }      
    }
    

    size_t size() const {return len;}
    T data(size_t x) const {return buffer[x];}
};


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  exampleClass<uint8_t> myObject = {0,1,2,3}; 

  Serial.println(myObject.size());
  Serial.println(myObject.data(0));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(1));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(2));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(3));


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: To the close voters because "off-topic": Since the Arduino build system does magic under the hood, it can well be the "culprit." Therefore, I see this question as on-topic.

Comment: The underlying compiler system is a common GCC, therefore I don't think that the compiler is limited. However, my current situation does not allow me to investigate by reproducing the issue. -- In the meantime, would you mind to [edit] your question and extend the provided source to a minimal, **complete, and reproducible** example, please? You don't want each of us to invest that time,do you?

Comment: @thebusybee my bad, I'll sure add a complete, and reproducible example

Comment: Just a random thought: does it work if you initialize the vector with `cpstd::vector<unsigned char> myVector{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};` (without the `=`)?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I did try, but the same happens, since the problem is that the compiler wont convert {x, x, x} to a cpstd::initializer_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been messing around with the minimal example code and found a working solution, I'll post the solution just in case someone finds themselves having the same issue on the future, the only downside is that it feels a bit hacky to my taste, I still wonder if there is a better solution. And would gratly appreciate any feedback.

I found out that the compiler does not ackowledges the initializer_list class for braced enclosed initializers if the class is not under the namespace std.

The way I came arround this problem lies on using the preprocessor directive below:

```
#if __has_include(<initializer_list>)
```

With this line conditional compilation takes place, and we can specify what to do whenever std::initializer_list is present or not.

- If std::initializer_list is not present an implementation is provided.
- cpstd::intitlizer_list is only a template alias of std::intitializer_list

minimal sketch with the solution:

```
#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <stddef.h> 

namespace std {

  template<typename T>
  class initializer_list {
  public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = const T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using const_iterator = const T*;

  private:
    const_iterator _M_array;
    size_type _M_len;

    constexpr initializer_list(const T* array, size_type size) noexcept
      : _M_array(array), _M_len(size) {}

  public:
    constexpr initializer_list() noexcept
      : _M_array(nullptr), _M_len(0) {}

    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept {
      return _M_len;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
      return _M_array;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept {
      return _M_array + _M_len;
    }
  };
}

namespace cpstd {
  template<class T>
  using initializer_list = std::initializer_list<T>;
}

template<typename T>
class exampleClass{
  protected:
    T buffer[10];
    size_t len;

  public:
    exampleClass(): len(0) {}
    exampleClass(cpstd::initializer_list<T> il){
      len = il.size();
      for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
        buffer[i] = *(il.begin()+i);
      }
    }

    exampleClass& operator=(cpstd::initializer_list<T> il){
      len = il.size();
      for(auto i = il.begin(); i < il.end(); i++){
        buffer[i] = *i;
      }      
    }

    size_t size() const {return len;}
    T data(size_t x) const {return buffer[x];}
};


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  exampleClass<uint8_t> myObject = {0,1,2,3}; 

  Serial.println(myObject.size());
  Serial.println(myObject.data(0));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(1));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(2));
  Serial.println(myObject.data(3));


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: Well done! Unfortunately answer should not contain follow-up questions, and the one about the keyword looks as non-Arduino specific, too. I suggest to post this one separately on [so].

Comment: I added the questions in my answer in case someone else wanted to add another answer, I think those are arduino specific questions because it implies using the arduino toolchain to reproduce the problems, I did not have this issues when compiling on other systems

Comment: As I commented, the underlying compiler is a common GCC. There is apparently nothing Arduino specific. However, this second question is a different issue, and as such needs its own question. You might want to link back to here. Please note that this is not a forum.

Comment: @thebusybee, you're right, im removing the questions from the answer